# Android - Как показать SnackBar?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio

Как показать SnackBar из библиотеки поддержки Material Support LIbrary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Snackbar.make(mDrawerLayout, "Your message", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
.setAction(getString(R.string.text_undo), this)
.show();
```

Источник: [Исследуем новую Android Design Support Library. Часть 1](http://java-help.ru/exploring-the-new-android-design-support-library-part-1/)